# Content's visibility is very small in mobile view

Tags: html, css, responsive

[My Website Link](http://www.testing.wi2wi.com/).
My problem is,
Latest News section in my website(above footer), is not displayed properly in the mobile view.
The contents are very small, very difficult for the user to read it.
Can anyone suggest me any method or some correction in CSS, so that the contents are clearly visible.
Thank you.

Comment: Please go read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/10283047), and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Place this after the camera.css is initialized.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    #camera_wrap_448 .camera_caption > div div.camera_caption_desc {
        font-size:3em !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because of the many !importants in your code, the last one will override every important.  Thats why it probably not worked

Comment: thanks a lot jayruben. But camera.css is for the home slider. I want change font sizes of the Latest News section(right above the footer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use VW instead of PX on both your height and font-size.

I also notice that there is a responsive problem in your "Product Portfolio when on  1199px upto 481px screen viewport.

Comment: Thanks alot. Exactly "Product portfolio" has responsive issue? Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @SubhamKotnala,  I can help you, if you provide the source code of your "product portfolio" section I'll try to fix it on jsfiddle

Comment: you can send a code via jsfiddle. send only the product forlio seciton with the css and html, so i can help.

Comment: hello... can give me the solution?

Comment: Thanks a lot. can u also help me with the latest news section. i tried what u told but didnt work.

Comment: source for that on jsfiddle also

Comment: can i get the solution?